# Android Studio run on device fail on Windows 10 N X64

Tags: java, android

have Android Studio 1.3(JDK 1.7.80 x64) under windows 10
gradle build success, but when i run my app i've got an error

```
08-07 11:47:12.414    2030-2030/com.nexetic.valo E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta', referenced from method com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>
```

When I remove Crashlytics I ve still have lot of errors about `"Could not find class"`

Any ideas ?

`08-07 11:47:12.418    2030-2030/com.nexetic.valo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nexetic.valo, PID: 2030
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.<init>(Kit.java:43)
            at com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers.<init>(Answers.java:28)
            at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:29)
            at com.nexetic.valo.application.NexeticApplication.onCreate(NexeticApplication.java:27)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Updated:
I have completely remove fabric from my project. Now I have athoner issue

`08-07 12:25:48.661    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7725/com.nexetic.valo D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 18192 (IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2) in Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType;
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0018
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/process/BitmapProcessor;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/process/BitmapProcessor;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/display/BitmapDisplayer;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/process/BitmapProcessor;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/process/BitmapProcessor;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/display/BitmapDisplayer;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/display/BitmapDisplayer;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/process/BitmapProcessor;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/process/BitmapProcessor;)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa8ce3b20)
08-07 12:25:48.673    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nexetic.valo, PID: 7720
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions$Builder.<init>(DisplayImageOptions.java:212)
            at com.nexetic.valo.application.NexeticApplication.onCreate(NexeticApplication.java:25)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 12:25:51.065    7720-7720/com.nexetic.valo I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 7720 SIG: 9`

P.S. I tried to create a new clean project. And it build and run fine on my emulator.

Comment: Were you sure to remove all imports?

Comment: Yes, I've build several times before success. I have errors not about "Crashlytics" after remove, but about many other classes. P.S. At my Mac all work fine. It's just on windows issue.

Comment: I think that issue in my specific project. Because I creating new with same dependencies and it works and run fine. But whats wrong with this current project? I cant find :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was mutidex issue.

I added "multiDexEnabled" into build.gradle:

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.nexetic.valo'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName '0.14.5a'
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }`

And make a patch for

[image: Here is a diff from bitbucket]